# How do you make a union in NASM?

Tags: nasm

I need to replicate a C-style union in Nasm, but can not find out how.

I need

```
r_eax dd 0
r_ax dw 0
```

where r_ax should reside in the same memory location as the low 16 bits of r_eax.

In C, this would be:

```
union RegType {
    long eax;
    short ax;
} reg_a;
```

I understand that Nasm does not care about variable sizes, but I still would like to be able to use different reference / variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really easily. The `EQU` directive means "make this symbol the same as another one" - so you can simply write `r_ax EQU r_eax` in your example.

This even works if you use NASM's "local notation" (which I highly recommend...)

```
STRUC Reg_A
    .eax RESD 1
    .ax EQU .eax
    .al EQU .ax
    .ah EQU ????? ; Ummm!
ENDSTRUC
```

I'd rearrange it as this, though:

```
STRUC Reg_A
    .al RESB 1
    .ah RESB 1
    .eah RESW 1  ; Not a real symbol - but NASM won't allow unnamed members
    .ax EQU .al
    .eax EQU .ax
ENDSTRUC
```

Comment: Thanks! Follow up question: where was this information available? I spent quite a bit of time googling for the answer and browsing various documentation, but didn't find it.

Comment: The short answer is: the NASM documentation on http://www.nasm.us/ . The longer answer is: painful experience. I _really_ dislike NASM for only one reason: see http://wiki.osdev.org/JohnBurger:NASMCritique . But it does allow all sorts of shortcuts...